# ReorderableListView "scrollable.of() was called with a context that does not contain a scrollable widget"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a simple to do app with flutter, and while implementing reorderable list as in the title i encountered a problem. I tried wraping it with column and expanded end unfortunatly run out of ideas. Any solutions?

```
body: ReorderableListView.builder(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: db.toDoList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final key = db.toDoList[index];
          return ToDoTile(
            deleteFunction:(context) => deleteTask(index),
            taskName: db.toDoList[index][0], 
            taskCompleted: db.toDoList[index][1], 
            onChanged:(value) => checkBoxChanged(value, index),
            key: ValueKey(key),);
            
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that the problem will be solved if you wrap it with SingleChildScrollView widget. I hope the error is resolved.
[Scrollable.of() was called with a context that does not contain a Scrollable widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74888370/scrollable-of-was-called-with-a-context-that-does-not-contain-a-scrollable-wid?rq=2)

Comment: i tried it, but when i wrap ReorderableListView.builder with it, entire page goes blank

Comment: Can you wrap your code in a Container() before using SingleChildScrollView()? If a certain width and height values ​​are given to the container, I think that size-related errors will not occur in the application.

Comment: it dosent seem to work, i tried with column and expanded too, although, when i wrap it with container and assinging random height, something like 100000 istead of all blank white screen, I am able to see AppBar. Do you need me to submit more of my code>?

Comment: Let's try your code in Scaffold as in the example. If this method doesn't work, share some more of your code and I'll try to solve it.  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView/ReorderableListView.builder.html